# What would be the most efficient way to find an object in an array of objects with distinct value which is an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, computer-science

I initially got this question in an interview few months back & have gotten around to solve it now.

So we have this array of objects & the goal is to find an an object with actors that haven't appeared in a movie more than once. So basically find a movie with unique actors.

```js
[
  {
    name: 'The Dark Knight',
    rating: 'PG-13',
    year: 2012,
    bestScene: {
      name: 'fight',
      location: 'sewer',
      sceneLength: 10,
      actors: ['Christian Bale', 'Tom Hardy']
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Good Burger',
    rating: 'PG',
    year: 1994,
    bestScene: {
      name: 'jump',
      location: 'giant milkshake',
      sceneLength: 5,
      actors: ['Kenan Thompson', 'Kel Mitchell']
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Sharknado 2: The Second One',
    rating: 'TV-14',
    year: 2013
  },
  {
    name: 'The Big Short',
    rating: 'R',
    year: 2015,
    bestScene: {
      name: 'explanation',
      location: 'casino',
      sceneLength: 20,
      actors: ['Christian Bale', 'Steve Carrell']
    }
  }
]
```

And a goal I have set for myself is to solve it using functional way so naturally we need to weed out objects with no `bestScene` present like this:

```
const moviesWithActorsPresent = movies.filter((movie) => movie.bestScene)
```

I could then use `reduce` to construct an array of objects like this:

```
[
  { 'The Dark Knight': [ 'Christian Bale', 'Tom Hardy' ] },
  { 'Good Burger': [ 'Kenan Thompson', 'Kel Mitchell' ] },
  { 'The Big Short': [ 'Christian Bale', 'Steve Carrell' ] }
]
```

And then loop through using `for` or `forEach` & keep track of the actors in a temporary variable but that to me is not exactly an elegant solution.

What CS concept we can use here to solve it efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the `moviesWithActorsPresent`, create an object (or Map) counting up the number of occurrences of each actor in the entire array. Then you can `.find` an object for which `.every` actor has a count of exactly 1:

```js
const movies =[
  {
    name: 'The Dark Knight',
    rating: 'PG-13',
    year: 2012,
    bestScene: {
      name: 'fight',
      location: 'sewer',
      sceneLength: 10,
      actors: ['Christian Bale', 'Tom Hardy']
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Good Burger',
    rating: 'PG',
    year: 1994,
    bestScene: {
      name: 'jump',
      location: 'giant milkshake',
      sceneLength: 5,
      actors: ['Kenan Thompson', 'Kel Mitchell']
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Sharknado 2: The Second One',
    rating: 'TV-14',
    year: 2013
  },
  {
    name: 'The Big Short',
    rating: 'R',
    year: 2015,
    bestScene: {
      name: 'explanation',
      location: 'casino',
      sceneLength: 20,
      actors: ['Christian Bale', 'Steve Carrell']
    }
  }
];
const moviesWithActorsPresent = movies.filter((movie) => movie.bestScene)
const actorCounts = moviesWithActorsPresent.reduce((a, { bestScene }) => {
  const { actors } = bestScene;
  return Object.assign(
    {}, // don't mutate
    a, // prior counts
    ...actors.map(actor => ({ [actor]: (a[actor] || 0) + 1 }))
  );
}, {});
const movieWithUniqueActors = moviesWithActorsPresent.find(({ bestScene }) => (
  bestScene.actors.every(actor => actorCounts[actor] === 1)
));
console.log(movieWithUniqueActors);
```

It almost certainly doesn't matter, but you can put the `.filter` functionality into the `.reduce` if you want:

```js
const movies = [{
    name: 'The Dark Knight',
    rating: 'PG-13',
    year: 2012,
    bestScene: {
      name: 'fight',
      location: 'sewer',
      sceneLength: 10,
      actors: ['Christian Bale', 'Tom Hardy']
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Good Burger',
    rating: 'PG',
    year: 1994,
    bestScene: {
      name: 'jump',
      location: 'giant milkshake',
      sceneLength: 5,
      actors: ['Kenan Thompson', 'Kel Mitchell']
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Sharknado 2: The Second One',
    rating: 'TV-14',
    year: 2013
  },
  {
    name: 'The Big Short',
    rating: 'R',
    year: 2015,
    bestScene: {
      name: 'explanation',
      location: 'casino',
      sceneLength: 20,
      actors: ['Christian Bale', 'Steve Carrell']
    }
  }
];
const actorCounts = movies.reduce((a, { bestScene }) => {
  if (!bestScene) {
    return a;
  }
  const { actors } = bestScene;
  return Object.assign({}, // don't mutate
    a, // prior counts
    ...actors.map(actor => ({
      [actor]: (a[actor] || 0) + 1
    }))
  );
}, {});
const movieWithUniqueActors = movies.find(({ bestScene }) => (
  bestScene.actors.every(actor => actorCounts[actor] === 1)
));
console.log(movieWithUniqueActors);
```

Comment: I guess I was overly complicating the solution and TIL about `every`.

Comment: Looping over the array twice with filter then reduce is possibly less efficient than just doing reduce and filtering for *bestScene* in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You'd just need to create a function which groups `films by actors`, and then take only those that have `1` film.

```js
const group = (data) => data
  .reduce((res, { name, bestScene }) => {
    ((bestScene || {}).actors || []).forEach(actor => {
      
      res[actor] = (res[actor] || []).concat(name);
    });
    
    return res;
  }, {});

const solve = data => Object
  .entries(group(data))
  .filter(([author, films]) => films.length === 1)

const data = [
  {
    name: 'The Dark Knight',
    rating: 'PG-13',
    year: 2012,
    bestScene: {
      name: 'fight',
      location: 'sewer',
      sceneLength: 10,
      actors: ['Christian Bale', 'Tom Hardy']
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Good Burger',
    rating: 'PG',
    year: 1994,
    bestScene: {
      name: 'jump',
      location: 'giant milkshake',
      sceneLength: 5,
      actors: ['Kenan Thompson', 'Kel Mitchell']
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Sharknado 2: The Second One',
    rating: 'TV-14',
    year: 2013
  },
  {
    name: 'The Big Short',
    rating: 'R',
    year: 2015,
    bestScene: {
      name: 'explanation',
      location: 'casino',
      sceneLength: 20,
      actors: ['Christian Bale', 'Steve Carrell']
    }
  }
];

console.log(solve(data));
```